# jQuery Version Upgrade Issues: TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, easing

I upgraded my jQuery version from 2.1.1 to 3.3.1.

After version migration, I cannot see my slider functionality working properly.

I have included both jquery.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js.

Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

The code snippet to which the error is pointed to:

```
    var slider = $(elem).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: scope.config.mapValues.indexOf(scope.bandwidth),
        min: scope.config.min,
        step: scope.config.step,
        max: scope.config.mapValues.length-1,
        disabled: scope.disabledFlag,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.value > scope.maxLimit){
                return false;
            }
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.slideValue = scope.config.mapValues[ui.value];
            });
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            if(scope.bandwidth > scope.maxLimit){
                scope._resetBandWidth();
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    var currentValue = scope.config.mapValues[scope.maxLimit];
                    if(ui.value <= scope.maxLimit) {
                        currentValue = scope.config.mapValues[ui.value];
                    }
                    scope.bandwidth = currentValue;
                    scope.slideValue = currentValue;
                });
                return false;
            }
            scope.$apply(function() {
                var bandwidthValue = scope.config.mapValues[ui.value];
                scope.bandwidth = bandwidthValue;
                scope.slideValue = bandwidthValue;
            });
        }
    }).append(disableDiv);
```

Below images shows the error which i see in console.
[image: slider is not a function error image]

[jQuery-UI - “Cannot read property 'step' of undefined” error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE6hk.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure your jquery and jquery-ui are loaded ? Can you see them in the console ? Also what is your elem ?

Comment: Please provide some more info and line where error is coming, possible then add full error.

Comment: Remember that browsers have developer mode that might assist in seeing more details around the error you are seeing, and also allow you to inject values into the page for debugging.

Comment: Check that you haven't accidentally included another copy of jQuery **after** adding jQuery-UI. That's usually the cause of missing plugins

Comment: i have included only one copy of JQuery and JQuery UI. I have included slim-build version of Jquery-3.3.1.

Answer (score -1):

Hi @Suhasini Venkatesh,

May be issue with minified JS. 
Instead of using `jquery.min.js` use [jquery-3.3.1.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js) with your `jquery-ui.min.js`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Edit:**

Slim removes some functions required in `jQuery UI` apparently. To fix this, use the full version of jQuery. for more details see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362029/5813861)

Hope that work for you. If not let me know in comments.

Comment: hi yash, thanks but inclusion of uncompressed version is breaking the entire application UI. I have included jQuery slim version. i hope that is breaking my slider functionality with error "slider is not a function" but if i include normal js file (not slim but minified) that is breaking drop-down hover highlight funtionality(all available options are highlighted at once) with error "w.easing is not a function".

Comment: @Suhasini Venkatesh, i updated my answer. check it and see it is helpful to you or not.

Comment: i tried with full version of jQuery, as mentioned earlier that is breaking drop-down hover highlight funtionality(all available options are highlighted at once) with error "w.easing is not a function".